# PFUser and Facebook in Parse iOS API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am trying to create a [Login and SignUp page using Parse Mobile platform](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-9zk2ArATI&feature=plcp). The matter is I want to connect my App user to his facebook. I could make it works using [Facebook Users](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers).

The thing is when we click on the facebook button, if the facebook id is not linked to any user, it creates a new user in the system. That's what I don't want.

So I force to Create my own mechanism for facebook connection:

```
if(![_prefs boolForKey:@"facebook"]) {
        [_login.logInView.facebookButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        if(!user)
            [_login.logInView.facebookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstTimeFBConnect) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        else if(user.isNew)
            [_login.logInView.facebookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fbConnNewUser) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
```

As you see In this code I used UserDefault, everything is perfect until when I uninstall the app and install again, all UserDefault will be reseted, but the link between user and facebook in my Parse cloud not.

What I want to have is:

The first time when user install the App and click on the facebook button, I can check if this facebook id is connected to any registered user in the system.

If yes, return TRUE.
If not return FALSE.

I could not find any useful code in Parse yet.